# SeaFile Docker - Disable SSL v3

Tags: nginx, docker

I have just SeaFile running in Docker, scanning the public interface I can see SSLv3 and TLS1.0 are enabled. I'd like to disable them but I'm at a loss as to where that would be configured in this setup.

I launched the container with

```
docker run -d --name seafile \
  -e SEAFILE_SERVER_LETSENCRYPT=true \
  -e SEAFILE_SERVER_HOSTNAME=seafile.example.com \
  -e SEAFILE_ADMIN_EMAIL=me@example.com \
  -e SEAFILE_ADMIN_PASSWORD=a_very_secret_password \
  -v /opt/seafile-data:/shared \
  -p 8080:80 \
  -p 8443:443 \
  seafileltd/seafile:latest
```

It's running nginx as the webserver, i have the nginx configuration in the docker merged folder, effectively /etc/nginx, but I can't find anywhere the options for configuring the available ciphers.

`grep -i -r "ssl_protocols" /etc/nginx/` returns zero results and after a bunch of digging through google results and bits of documentation I'm no further forward.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Added the following lines to the seafile.nginx.conf.template file in the image and restarted seafile

added

```
ssl_protocols TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
```

To the server block immediately before the `ssl_ciphers` line in the conf file.

You can locate the path to the conf template with

```
/var/lib/docker/>find ./ | grep seafile.nginx.conf.template
```